# Dynamic Partition Creation in mysql using stored procedure and event scheduler

Tags: mysql, database-partitioning

I have a table on which I would like to create an auto-partitioning scheme by first partitioning the table by month and then sub-partitioning by id.

I recently learned that mysql does not support auto-partitioning and the only way to create dynamic partitions is by stored-procedures and event schedulers.

My requirement is that new entries are automatically created into new partitions and after a year,the old records are deleted automatically.

How do I do this?

Please suggest me some methods on how to implement stored procedures and event schedulers to support dynamic partitioning and also to delete the  old records automatically.

This is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `ORDER_HISTORY` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Invoice_Number` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `User_Id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `Store_ID` mediumint(6) NOT NULL,
  `Store_Entity_Id` mediumint(8) NOT NULL,
  `Item_List` blob NOT NULL,
  `Order_Time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Payment_Time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `Payment_Type` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
  `Payment_Retry_Attempts` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Payment_TransactionID` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `Sub_Total_Amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `CGST_Tax_Amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `SGST_Tax_Amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Other_Tax_Amount` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Service_Fee` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Earned_Cashback_Amount` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Used_Cashback_Amount` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Used_Coupon` mediumint(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Used_Coupon_Discount` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Grand_Total_Amount` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `Status` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
  `Manager_Id` smallint(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Store_Name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `User_Phone_Number` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Manager_Phone_Number` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Manager_Name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Id_UNIQUE` (`Id`),
  KEY `Store_ID_idx` (`Store_ID`),
  KEY `Table_ID_idx` (`Store_Entity_Id`),
  KEY `Phone_Number_idx` (`User_Id`),
  KEY `oh_payment_type_id_fk_idx` (`Payment_Type`),
  KEY `oh_coupon_id_fk_idx` (`Used_Coupon`),
  KEY `oh_status_id_fk_idx` (`Status`),
  KEY `oh_manager_id_fk` (`Manager_Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `oh_coupon_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Used_Coupon`) REFERENCES `COUPONS` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `oh_manager_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Manager_Id`) REFERENCES `MANAGER` (`Id`),
  CONSTRAINT `oh_payment_type_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Payment_Type`) REFERENCES `PAYMENT_TYPES` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `oh_status_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Status`) REFERENCES `STATUS` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `oh_store_entity_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Store_Entity_Id`) REFERENCES `STORE_ENTITY` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `oh_store_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Store_ID`) REFERENCES `STORE` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `oh_user_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`User_Id`) REFERENCES `USERS` (`Id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How much rows the table will have by average?

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan-the table actually has its entries inserted from another table when it is updated.so the number of rows can't be predetermined

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan-the data in the table will increase by many folds in the future

Comment: may I consider the table have at most 1 million records also kindly share the schema structure.

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan-+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field                  | Type          | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------------------+---------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Id                     | bigint(20)    | NO   | PRI | NULL              |       |
| Invoice_Number         | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL              |       |
| User_Id                | int(10)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |       |

Comment: Could you please `SHOW CREATE TABLE  table_name;` execute this query and copy paste the `Create Table` field's value. By the way which version of MySQL are you using.

Comment: I have pasted the schema in the edited question above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all partitioning is the best use case for the issue which you faced. The reason is the storage engine which you use `innodb` is transaction based engine. So it records all the actions done in a log results in higher `I/O` resource. And for delete even it requires more resource. But partition with sub-partition is overkill because you need to clean the table data yearly once so you can use `RANGE COLUMN` clause with `cron` job which run yearly once.

You can check your MySQL supports `partition` by executing the following command:

```
SHOW PLUGINS;
```

This will show a tabular data in that please check you have `partition` in `name` column with `ACTIVE` in the `Status` column.

**Partition Types:**

There are two type of partition. They are vertical partition (partition by column) which is not supported by MySQL and the second one is horizontal partition (partition by row).

**Partition Definition:**

```
        PARTITION partition_name
        [VALUES
            {LESS THAN {(expr | value_list) | MAXVALUE}
            |
            IN (value_list)}]
        [[STORAGE] ENGINE [=] engine_name]
        [COMMENT [=] 'string' ]
        [DATA DIRECTORY [=] 'data_dir']
        [INDEX DIRECTORY [=] 'index_dir']
        [MAX_ROWS [=] max_number_of_rows]
        [MIN_ROWS [=] min_number_of_rows]
        [TABLESPACE [=] tablespace_name]
        [(subpartition_definition [, subpartition_definition] ...)]
```

**SOLUTION:**

**Step 1:**
Alter the table schema with partioning like this (Reference link 3)

```
CREATE TABLE members (
    firstname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    lastname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(35),
    joined DATE NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY RANGE COLUMNS(joined) (
    /*PARTITION y2013 VALUES LESS THAN ('2014-01-01'),
    PARTITION y2014 VALUES LESS THAN ('2015-01-01'),
    PARTITION y2015 VALUES LESS THAN ('2016-01-01'),
    PARTITION y2016 VALUES LESS THAN ('2017-01-01'),*/ #This are older partition it may deleted before 2017 itself
    PARTITION y2017 VALUES LESS THAN ('2018-01-01'),
    PARTITION future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE
);
```

**Step 2:**
You can use any programming language like PHP, Ruby, Python, Perl to create this query dynamically. Consider this is running in 01 January 2019 using cron.

```
ALTER TABLE members 
    DROP PARTITION y2017;
ALTER TABLE members 
    REORGANIZE PARTITION future INTO
        y2018 VALUES LESS THAN ('2019-01-01'),
        future VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE;
```

Query to get previous years with format:

```
SELECT concat('Y', YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))) as prev_year
```

change the interval to get further older year.

**Step 3:**
Execute the above query yearly once using any scheduler like cron. For e.g.

```
@yearly /home/meenu/ubuntu/bin/annual-maintenance.sh
```

**REFERENCES:**

**More On Partition-ing:**

1. [Create table partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-table-partitioning)
2. [Partitioning official document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html)
3. [Partitioning range](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-range.html)

**Cron:**

4. [Cron examples with explanation](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples)
5. [Running MySQL query periodically](https://dsharpdotnet.wordpress.com/2013/07/04/how-to-use-cronjob-to-execute-periodical-mysql-queries/)

**Big Deletes:**

6. [Big deletes various alternatives](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig)

**Partition Maintenance:**

7. [Partition Maintenance](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint)